# Can you reach higher efficiencies of the Otto cycle by changing the sequence slightly?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, ideal-gas, heat-engine

If we take the common Otto cycle we have two isochoric and two adiabatic processes, plus exhaust & intake stroke.

Would it be more efficient to do the following:

1. Instead of cutting off the adiabatic expansion at a certain volume, continue with the expansion until the internal pressure equals the external pressure?
2. Using the exhaust stroke for heat rejection?
3. Instead of an intake stroke, push liquid into the system at ignition volume (volume of isochoric heating) to avoid the work needed for compression?

I am more interested in the theoretical efficiency instead of the real application viability (i.e. if the adibatic expansion would require too much volume, or getting as much fuel into the chamber as possible per cycle)

Comment: as for (2) - what is heat rejection in a way that could be used in an exhaust stroke?

Comment: If the gas is at ambient pressure (as in my first point) the remaining heat is exhausted as part of an open isobaric compression into the surroundings.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note before I begin, sticking to the Otto cycle kind of limits the sheer theoretical reflections, because it somewhat is made as a most simplified model of the otto piston engine. So it's already not sheer theoretical ideas, you already get limitations like: the expansion stroke and the compression stroke are the same displaced volume etc..
As to your points:

1. Yes you would get a higher efficiency as in "more work done" relative to the "combustion heat input". The reason for cutting off the expansion at max volume is  a practical one - as in the piston has reached bottom dead center (BDC). If you want the pressure to be at ambient pressure at that point, you would need a significantly reduced cylinder filling during intake, which leads to greatly reduced power output for a given displacement. That actually happens during part load when the throttle is closed. Effectively though the extra losses introduced that way outweigh the efficiency gains due to the low pressure expansion.
2. - 
3. In order to achieve the thermodynamic state (pressure, temperature) of the air/fuel mixture at top dead center, you will need to compress it, whether done internally or externally, and then fed into the cylinder. If you find a different type of fuel - say rocket booster powder, then yes you could do without the intake stroke AND the compression stroke. But that means that your cycle changes, it's no longer Otto: now you have (1) isobaric expulsion, then (2) close all valves,  introduce the fuel pellet at TDC fire it: isochoric heating, and (3) expansion stroke doing the work.

Comment: so regarding (3): Does that mean that the compression stroke is only necessary because of the fuel used, and different fuels (which have better ignition properties at ambient state) would allow for a more efficient (only in terms of Output : Input) cycles?